# Unit testing Azure table storage classes

Tags: azure, mocking, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have been trying to find if i can easily isolate and test azure table storage dependencies but to to no avail. I believe its really difficult to mock/fake ATS dependencies. I am surprised at how the Azure team  could ignore this in the age of TDD/BDD etc. Or is it am i missing something? From my undersntanding it has very minimal interface/abstract classes which make isolating them difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically should be mocking repositories that retrieve or persist data.  These can be mocked quiet easily.  Why are you trying to mock the ATS dependencies themselves?

Furthermore, TableServiceEntity is not required to be inherited from.  Feel free to implement your own interface instead - if for some reason you need to mock entities themselves.

Comment: I agree. But then don't you ever write unit test cases for repositories? So when try to write unit test cases for repositories how do you isolate ATS dependencies?I am trying to find out how people go about unit testing ATS. But i believe that every piece of code that you write has to be unit tested including repositories?Do you disagree?

Comment: I typically choose to NOT put business logic into repositories, so I don't have my teams unit test repositories themselves, only their consumers.  IMHO, this is one of the core reasons for having repositories - so that they can be mocked.